# What's the structure of a matchmaking server?

Tags: mysql

This is my current structure of my matches table:

```
id, title, description, max_players, host_username, host_ip
```

and there's another table called matches_players:

```
match_id, player_username
```

This requires two queries to get the matches list and the player count of each one, so is there a better way?

I'm using:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `matches_players` WHERE `match_id` = ?
```

to get the number of players in a match.

Server inserts one row to the matches table, and then another one to add the host to the matches_players table.

It is working, but it makes the code more complex, saving the matches list, then doing lot of queries to get the players number. I was wondering if there is a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
SELECT id
      ,title
      ,DESCRIPTION
      ,max_players
      ,host_username
      ,host_ip
      ,(
           SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM   matches_players
           WHERE  match_id = id
       ) AS player_count
FROM   matches
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT m.id,
       COUNT(mp.player_username) AS player_count
FROM   matches m
       LEFT OUTER JOIN matches_players mp
            ON  m.id = mp.match_id
GROUP BY
       m.id
```

Using a `JOIN` is much faster than doing a subselect for each `ID`.

If you want additional columns from the `matches` table, include them in the `GROUP BY`-clause.